# Querying a feature layer with a large amount of points

Tags: arcgis-js-api

Working in ArcGIS JS API 4.22:

I am trying to query a feature layer (polygons) with a large amount of points (~1000) in order to find which polygons the points intersect with (by name only, no need for geometries. Doing this with a loop for each point individually is extremely slow and errors out. I've tried condensing the points to a multipoint geometry in hopes of speeding the process to no avail. Is there a solution to this that I am just overlooking?

Added code:

```
const layer = new FeatureLayer({
            url: "https://arcgis-server.lsa.umich.edu/arcgis/rest/services/IFR/glahf_classification_poly/MapServer/0",
            outFields: ["AEU_Code"],
        });
//gets a server error at about 250 points
var multipoint = new Multipoint({
            points: [
                [-86, 45],
                [-85, 47],
                [-84, 49]
            ]
        });

        const query = new Query();
        query.geometry = multipoint;
        query.outSpatialReference = { wkid: 102100 };
        query.returnGeometry = false;
        query.outFields = ["AEU_Code"];

        layer.queryFeatures(query).then(function (results) {
            console.log(results.features);  // prints the array of features to the console
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code with your loop?

Comment: @Carson added code above using the multipoint. Ultimately, I'm first querying an api to gather points and then compiling them into a multipoint (simplified example in the code), after which querying those points from a feature layer to return poylgons where there is spatial overlap. The problem is that I have some multipoint features with ~1000 points, which then makes the query last minutes and often time out.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two separate layers in this situation right? A polygon layer and a points layer? Use the pairwise intersect tool, it should result in an feature class where the attribute table has all of your points along with the fields from the polygon layer they intersect with. 1000 points really isn't that many, this should not be very computationally intense.

If this is not what you're doing can you be more descriptive with the data you have and what you are trying to accomplish?

The other way I interpret the question is that you already have the feature layer I described, but are trying to query it in some way. If this is the case can you elaborate on what you are trying to glean from the data? I don't understand why you would need to query each point individually.

Comment: Right so I am working in JavaScript and not in ArcGIS Pro unfortunately (I'm building a web app), so those tools aren't available.

Comment: Oh I understand, sorry I can't be of much assistance.

Comment: No worries!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I check the polygon service and it has 77 features. If you can load all the polygons in the view, then one possible option is to do the intersection in the client instead of the server. In this way at least you avoid timeout issues, you will have to time it to see how long it takes.

In order to to the intersection in the client use the layer view instead of the layer, [ArcGIS JS API - FeatureLayerView queryFeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-FeatureLayerView.html#queryFeatures).